# date at time zone related syntax and semantic differences

Tags: postgresql, datetime, etl, postgresql-9.3, timestamp-with-timezone

Question: How is query 1 "semantically" different than the query 2?

Background:

1. To extract data from the table in a db which is at my localtime zone (AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York').
2. The table has data for various time zones such as the 'America/Los_Angeles', America/North_Dakota/New_Salem and such time zones. 
   (Postgres stores the table data for various timezones in my local timezone)
3. So, everytime I retrieve data for a different location other than my localtime, I convert it to its relevant timezone for evaluation purposes..

Query 1:

```
test_db=# select count(id) from click_tb where date::date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' = '2017-05-22'::date  AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';
 count 
-------
  1001
(1 row)
```

Query 2:

```
test_db=# select count(id) from click_tb where (date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')::date = '2017-05-22'::date;
 count 
-------
     5
(1 row)
```

Table structure:

```
test_db=# /d+ click_tb
                                                               Table "public.click_tb"
              Column               |           Type           |                          Modifiers                          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                                | integer                  | not null default nextval('click_tb_id_seq'::regclass)       | plain    |              | 
 date                              | timestamp with time zone |                                                             | plain    |              | 

Indexes:
    "click_tb_id" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "click_tb_date_index" btree (date)
```

```
The query 1 and query 2 do not produce consistent results.
As per my tests, the below query 3, semantically addresses my requirement.
Your critical feedback is welcome.
```

```
Query 3:
```

```
test_db=# select count(id) from click_tb where ((date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')::timestamp with time zone)::date = '2017-05-22'::date;
```

Comment: 1st question: why don't you just save all time information in UTC with an additional field that represents the timezone of that tupel?

Comment: General rule with any relational database: don't ever use a function against a table's field in a where clause.  It will make your query [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), which means it cannot use an index, so it will scan the entire table applying your function to every row.  This is really bad for performance, especially on large tables.

Comment: @MattJohnson: unless you create an index with that (function) expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not convert the timestamp field.  Instead, do a range query.  Since your data is already using a `timestamp with time zone` type, just set the time zone of your query accordingly.

```
set TimeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
select count(id) from click_tb
where date >= '2017-01-02'
  and date <  '2017-01-03';
```

Note how this uses a half open interval of the dates (at start of day in the set time zone).  If you want to compute the second date from your first date, then:

```
set TimeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
select count(id) from click_tb
where date >= '2017-01-02'
  and date <  (timestamp with time zone '2017-01-02' + interval '1 day');
```

This properly handles daylight saving time, and sargability.

Comment: Thanks for the SET option suggestion. Using SET LOCAL or SET SESSION options minimizes the chances of error, eliminates inconsistency with typecasting and allows to use the range query.